# Changing Area Output (somewhere to 8th decimal point) each time ArcPy script run?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, area

I currently have shapefile of US PUMAS and another feature shapefile (call it feature X). I am using ArcPy to project both of these files to the following projection coordinate system (using Project_management):

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/nad_1983_contiguous_usa_albers/html/

After projecting, I use intersect_analysis and then CalculateAreas_stat to compute the intersection areas. Finally I output a .csv file, which I then use to compute area weighted means.

The issue is that every time I run my simple script, the intersection areas vary by a small amount (somewhere to the 8th decimal point). These small changes are impacting my analysis.

If this is a GIS precision issue or if I making a mistake, how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: I suggest loading the shapefiles into a file geodatabase, don't work with the shapefiles which have lower precision. Another thing - why do you use the CalculateAreas_stat, any specific reason for that? I suggest using the Calculate Field with the !shape.area! http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000.

Comment: Shapefiles have lower precision? That's not correct. Shapefiles and (high precision) geodatabases are both using the equivalent of double precision.